# strange behaviour when using captured naming group to define alias

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a very simple virtualhost configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name datavis.dev.localserver.fr;

    root /var/www;

    location ~ ^\/datavis\/(?<datarep>[\w]+) {
        alias /var/www/data-${datarep}-front;
        autoindex on;
    }
```

}

I have 2 index.html in 2 dirs : /var/www/data-test1-front and /var/www/data-test2-front

When i try http://datavis.dev.localserver.fr/datavis/test1/ in my browser i have this return in the error logs:

```
2016/10/04 17:36:43 [error] 4614#4614: *1 opendir() "/var/www/data-test1-fron" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.56.1, server: datavis.dev.localserver.fr, request: "GET /datavis/info/ HTTP/1.1", host: "datavis.dev.localserver.fr"
```

The last letter is removed... do anyone know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You alias doesn't ends with `/`, but `autoindex` want it and strip last char from path. `index index.html` wont work too, because result path will be `/var/www/data-test-frontindex.html`. So, all you need is to add `/`:

```
location ~ ^\/datavis\/(?<datarep>[\w]+)/ {
    alias /var/www/data-${datarep}-front/;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not explicit, [the example in the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) shows the entire URI being constructed on the `alias` statement, when enclosed within a regular expression location.

So, although this doesn't directly answer your question, a working alternative configuration could be:

```
location ~ ^/datavis/(\w+)(.*)$ {
    alias /var/www/data-$1-front$2;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Obviously named captures would work too.

Comment: Thanks, yes it works :), 
I just wanted too know why i had to add a 2nd capturing-group, looks like a bug to me